# Get DTD from an XML file

Tags: java, xml

How can I get in Java the DTD file name specified in an xml file?

So, if I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE TEI SYSTEM "dtd-file.dtd"  [
[
<!ENTITY c24r SYSTEM "c2r.jpg" NDATA JPEG>
<!NOTATION JPEG SYSTEM "image/jpeg">
<!ELEMENT figure EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST figure entity CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
```

I want the string "dtd-file.dtd"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the [document type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getDoctype%28%29)'s system ID use [`DocumentType#getSystemId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/DocumentType.html#getSystemId%28%29):

```
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(someXmlInputStream);
String systemId = document.getDoctype().getSystemId();
```